# Apex Callout from Flow ([SObject (No ID),SObject (No ID)])

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I am trying to call from a flow to an InvocableMethod. The method return type is `List<List<SObject>>`.

When I run a basic flow (Flow Metadata Below) I get the following message [image]

- In the circled areas, you will notice that the first has two elements, which is correct (Based on the returned data) but no field data.
- the loop looks like it does not have any elements to loop through.

Below is the Class, the callout, and the Flow Metadata. If anyone could give me any insight as to what I am missing/doing wrong that would be great.

```
public class WSObjects {

    /**
     * obj for MDMItems
     */
    public class GetMDMItemObj{
        public String itemNumber {get; set;}
        public String vendorName {get; set;}
        public String vendorNumber {get; set;}
        public List<GetMDMItemObj> itemDataResp {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Callout

```
public with sharing class MDMItemCallout
{
    @InvocableMethod //List<List<SObject>> runMap(List<String> MDMItemNum)
    public static List<List<MDM_Item__c>> runMap()
    {
        List<List<MDM_Item__c>> listOfmdmItemsList = new List<List<MDM_Item__c>> ();
        List<MDM_Item__c> mbmItmList = new List<MDM_Item__c>();

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        //Mock endpoint
        request.setEndpoint('https://10f30857-1b14-484f-82dd-67a05aaaaf21.mock.pstmn.io/mdmItem');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            String responseBody = response.getBody();
            system.debug(responseBody);

            WSObjects.GetMDMItemObj mdmObj = new WSObjects.GetMDMItemObj();
            mdmObj.itemDataResp = new List<WSObjects.GetMDMItemObj>();

            System.debug('Try Catch');
            try{

                mdmObj = (WSObjects.GetMDMItemObj)JSON.deserialize(responseBody, WSObjects.GetMDMItemObj.class);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.debug(e);
            }
            System.debug('Final: '+mdmObj.itemDataResp);


            for(WSObjects.GetMDMItemObj itm: mdmObj.itemDataResp)
            {
                MDM_Item__c md = new MDM_Item__c();
                //md.Id = null;
                md.itemNumber__c = itm.itemNumber;
                md.vendorName__c = itm.vendorName;
                md.vendorNumber__c = itm.vendorNumber;

                mbmItmList.add(md);
            }
            listOfmdmItemsList.add(mbmItmList);
        }
        System.debug('List OF Lists'+listOfmdmItemsList);
        return listOfmdmItemsList;
    }
}
```

Flow Metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionCalls>
        <name>GetMDMitem</name>
        <label>GetMDMitem</label>
        <locationX>293</locationX>
        <locationY>56</locationY>
        <actionName>MDMItemCallout</actionName>
        <actionType>apex</actionType>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>returnedRecordsLoop</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <outputParameters>
            <assignToReference>ReturnedMDMItemsCollection</assignToReference>
            <name>output</name>
        </outputParameters>
    </actionCalls>
    <interviewLabel>MDM Item Update {!$Flow.CurrentDateTime}</interviewLabel>
    <label>MDM Item Update</label>
    <loops>
        <name>returnedRecordsLoop</name>
        <label>returnedRecordsLoop</label>
        <locationX>464</locationX>
        <locationY>53</locationY>
        <assignNextValueToReference>mdmLoopItem</assignNextValueToReference>
        <collectionReference>ReturnedMDMItemsCollection</collectionReference>
        <iterationOrder>Asc</iterationOrder>
    </loops>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>BuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processMetadataValues>
        <name>OriginBuilderType</name>
        <value>
            <stringValue>LightningFlowBuilder</stringValue>
        </value>
    </processMetadataValues>
    <processType>Flow</processType>
    <start>
        <locationX>50</locationX>
        <locationY>50</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>GetMDMitem</targetReference>
        </connector>
    </start>
    <status>Draft</status>
    <variables>
        <name>MDMItemNum</name>
        <dataType>String</dataType>
        <isCollection>false</isCollection>
        <isInput>true</isInput>
        <isOutput>true</isOutput>
        <value>
            <stringValue></stringValue>
        </value>
    </variables>
    <variables>
        <name>mdmLoopItem</name>
        <dataType>SObject</dataType>
        <isCollection>false</isCollection>
        <isInput>true</isInput>
        <isOutput>true</isOutput>
        <objectType>MDM_Item__c</objectType>
    </variables>
    <variables>
        <name>ReturnedMDMItemsCollection</name>
        <dataType>SObject</dataType>
        <isCollection>true</isCollection>
        <isInput>true</isInput>
        <isOutput>true</isOutput>
        <objectType>MDM_Item__c</objectType>
    </variables>
</Flow>
```

ENDPOINT mock data

```
{
 "itemDataResp": [
      {
        "vendorNumber": "123",
        "vendorName": "Vendor 1",
        "itemNumber": "6625"
      },
      {
        "vendorNumber": "1234",
        "vendorName": "Vendor 2",
        "itemNumber": "9887"
      }
]
}
```

Comment: is this flow -> invocable method going to get started from a trigger? If so, you can't do callouts in same Txn as a trigger (asking because this issue will dominate the solution)

Comment: @cropredy No, the flow will start from process builder. What I am doing now is running the flow from the debug option right in the flow.

Comment: But process builder is kicked off by a DML change which may be due to a trigger

Comment: @cropredy ok so I understand what you saying, with the testing I am doing wouldn't I see results when debugging in the flow without it starting from on?

Comment: My point is that if the call out has to be done async, there will be nothing to return to the flow

Comment: @cropredy -- true, but that's not the issue we're seeing here.